# Mail going to spam folder from Ubuntu 16.10 postfix

Tags: postfix-mta

I setup postfix on my server, that's subdomain. so main domain and subdomain IP is different. I am sending mail as support@maindomain.com from subdomain.maindomain.com.

Is there any way to avoid the emails going to spam.

Note: Email doesn't show emailed by.